# Send data to API from Arduino with ESP8285 Strange Error

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, wifi

I have an Arduino with few sensors, and I want to send all of data to my API over ESP8285 what is connected to the wifi.

Its almost working fine, except one thing.

I have these AT commands:

```
String postRequest =
    "POST /hello HTTP/1.1" + String("\r\n") +
    "Host: 192.168.88.186" + "\r\n" +
    "Cache-Control: no-cache" + "\r\n" +
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" + "\r\n" +
    "Content-Length: " + String(data.length()) + "\r\n\r\n" +
    String(data) + "\r\n";

void connectWifi()
{
  espclient.println("AT+CWMODE=1");
  String connectcmd = "AT+CWJAP=\"" + ssid + "\",\"" + w_password + "\"";
  espclient.println(connectcmd);

  delay(3000);
  if (espclient.find("OK"))
  {
    Serial.println("Connected!");
  }
  else
  {
    connectWifi();
    Serial.println("Cannot connect to wifi");
  }
}

void espStatus()
{
    String tmpResp = espclient.readString();
    Serial.print("ESPLOG:");
    Serial.println(tmpResp);
}

void httppost()
{
  espclient.println("AT+CIPMUX=0");
  espclient.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"" + server + "\",5000"); //start a TCP connection.
  if (espclient.find("OK"))
  {
    Serial.println("TCP connection ready");
  } else {
    espStatus();
  }
  espclient.println("AT+CIPSTATUS");
  espStatus();

  Serial.println("PRINT REQUEST ==================================");
  Serial.println(postRequest);
  Serial.println("PRINT REQUEST ==================================");

  espclient.println("AT+CIPSEND="+String(postRequest.length()));
  do {
    delay(1000);
    if (espclient.find(">"))
    {
      break;
    }
  }
  while(true);
  espclient.print(postRequest);
  delay(500);
  espStatus();
  espclient.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
}
```

**SETUP:**

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Starting the modules....");

  espclient.begin(9600);
  connectWifi();
  Serial.println("ESP Module is ready");
}
```

**LOOP:**

```
void loop() {
    httppost();
    delay(5000);
}
```

And I get this error(?) message:

```
TCP connection ready
ESPLOG: 
AT+CIPSTATUS

STATUS:2

OK

PRINT REQUEST ==================================
POST /hello HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.88.186
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 13
name=ESPModul

PRINT REQUEST ==================================
ESPLOG: Q�J5U�S�!*HZYlo QQA��HV�^\��
H��銒)       �&�C��y \�R
�r�+����H�

TCP connection ready
ESPLOG: 
AT+CIPSTATUS

STATUS:2

OK

PRINT REQUEST ==================================
POST /hello HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.88.186
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 13
name=ESPModul

PRINT REQUEST ==================================
ESPLOG: Q�J5U�S�!*HZYlo QQA��HV�^\��
H����)      �&AC��y \�R
�r�+����H�
```

**UPDATE** The new /error/ message:

```
ESPLOG:Q�J5U�SS�CT��he���EE))���H��
����    )�H��HK�
Ca����E�K�V,YCCb
```

**UPDATE2** I restarted the arduino, and now I am getting this:

```
TCP connection ready
PRINT REQUEST ==================================
POST /hello HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.88.186
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 13

name=ESPModul

PRINT REQUEST ==================================
ESPLOG:
AT+CIPSTATUS

STATUS:2

OK
AT+CIPSEND=155

link is not vAT+CIPCLOSE


ERROR
```

**UPDATE3**: This method is working

```
void testHTTP() 
{
  Serial.println("Establishing TCP connection");
  espclient.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"" + server + "\",5000");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("Sending out data…");
  espclient.println("AT+CIPSEND=16");
  espclient.println("GET / HTTP/1.1");
  espclient.println();
  espclient.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
}
```

If I connect the ESP to my PC with TTL adapter, and I write the commends manually, then its working fine. And yes, the ESP is connecting correctly to the wifi, I tested it.

The main solution was to put "`delay(1000);`" after "`CIPSEND=`".

I hope my fumbling can help to someone in the future.

Comment: add one more `\r\n` for mandatory empty line after HTTP request header. `"Content-Length: " + String(data.length()) + "\r\n\r\n" +`.

Comment: `Serial.println("ESPLOG: "+tmpResp)`, prints some random memory content at address calculated by the `+`. use `Serial.print("ESPLOG:"); Serial.println(tmpResp);`

Comment: wait for `>` after CIPSEND

Comment: @Juraj: No, why? Overload resolution for `"ESPLOG: "+tmpResp` will interpret it as `String("ESPLOG: ") + tmpResp`, which uses overloaded binary `+` for `String` type. Everything is correct in that expression: it does concatenate two `String`s into a new `String`. It is unnecessarily "heavy", but otherwise perfectly correct.

Comment: @Juraj Thanks for the advice, I tried what you said, but I have the same issue. The new error message is a bit different. I added the new message to the post.

Comment: you still print wrong and you still don't wait for `>`

Comment: @Juraj No, I just didn't updated in the code. But now I updated those parts.

Comment: try not to request status between connection and data sending

Comment: @AnT, "ESPLOG" is `const char*`. what does a `+` do for pointer type?

Comment: There's no "`+` for a pointer type" here. This is a binary `+`, which has **two** equally important operands. One operand is `const char[7]`, another is `String`. This launches a process called *overload resolution*. And overload resolution will conclude that the best match in this case is overloaded `operator +` for two `String` operands. It will let `const char[7]` to decay to `const char *` and then it will implicitly convert it to a temporary `String` object. Then it will add (concatenate) two `String` objects forming a `String` result.

Comment: To put it shorter, if just one operand of binary `+` is a `String` (no matter which), the other operand will typically be implicitly converted to a `String` as well. And you end up with concatenation and a new `String`.

Comment: @AnT, yes, you are right

Comment: @G3ph4z, did you set the baud rate of AT firmware to 9600 baud?

Comment: @Juraj Sorry, I was AFK. Yea, I changed the baud in the ESP's firmware. I will test the code without ESPStatus, as you said before.

Comment: So I tried, but nothing. It doesn't send me any packet, also I can ping the ESP modul.

Comment: maybe the esp8266 crashed on connecting because of insufficient powering